# pact -python for QA Team

Tags: pact, pact-python

i am trying to setup pact python project locally and facing issues. it would be great if you help me on these issues

It seems we have to use localhost:1234 from consumer side ?  . Can we  use real service in place of mocking service ?  If I use   localhost:1234 ,  pact was generated but if i use real service ,then error is coming up  **So my question is do we need to always use  Mock service ((localhost:1234) when we creating pacts from consumer side**

2nd issue : i am from QA Team and  thinking that pacts should be written by DEV team not QA  team . is my assumption correct ? if yes, how these pacts will help QA Team ?

consumer.py

```
    import requests
    def callAPI(self,inputString,Url):
    respone = requests.get(url+inputString).status_code
```

test_consumer.py:

```
 pact = Consumer ( 'consumer' ).has_pact_with ( Provider ( 'provider' ) )
      pact.start_service ()
      atexit.register ( pact.stop_service )


      def test_callAPI (self):
      url = 'http://localhost:1234'

      pact.given ( 'sending user name to Url'
                 ).upon_receiving (
        'once i get the respone from service'
      ).with_request (
        'get', '/' ).will_respond_with ( 200)

     with pact:
        result = callAPI (url)
        self.assertEqual ( result['status_code'], 200 )
```

Thank  you in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code must hit the mock server else we can't be sure what you're expecting is actually true. Contract testing uses this to guarantee it's requirements on a provider.

You can also tell Pact to use any port, that's just the default.

> should devs write them ... how will it help the QA team?

Well the short answer is yes, they really should be written by those writing the code. Is that a bad thing? As a QA I would imagine this makes your job easier as quality is automatically higher and you can focus on more important activities instead of writing automation tests.